# How do I disable edition of a PyGtk Combobox?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want the user to be able to select the items on a PyGTK ComboBox, while not being able to write in the combo. He/She should be allowed just to select one of the items.
So I can't use set_active(False), for it will disable the combo.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Don't you want a list box/drop-down list, rather than combo box, if the user shouldn't be allowed to add new items? The **whole point** of a combo box is to allow free-text entry to be added to a list - see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box

Comment: How are you creating the combo box? A combo box created with `gtk.combo_box_new_text()` (as opposed to `gtk.combo_box_new_text_with_entry()`) should not sport a write-in entry field.

Comment: @jonrsharpe A combo box doesn't have to necessarily imply an entry field for write-ins, the wikipedia page says as much (*The term "combo box" is sometimes used to mean "drop-down list".*). In GTK+ the term combo box refers to a drop-down list with or without an entry attached.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm creating using an old Glade version (2.12.1). This is an application build in Python 2.5 that I'm doing some maintenance. Due to some technical problems I'm tied to this version unfortunately. I've tried to upgrade a number of times but it triggers a lot of problems and my company doesn't want to rewrite it. So I'm stuck in this version.

Comment: In that case check the .ui file that Glade produced; does the combobox have the `has_entry` property set?

Comment: No it hasn't. Here is the relevant portion of the .ui file realted to the combobox: http://pastebin.com/gvxBdKHC

Comment: Ah, in GTK+ 2 GtkComboBoxEntry was also a separate class. Try changing that to just GtkComboBox.

Comment: worked. thanks. put as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+ 2 has a type GtkComboBoxEntry that always has the entry box you don't want (and handles some model-related things). Your Glade file uses a GtkComboBoxEntry. Change it to GtkComboBox and, assuming everything else is set up properly (your model is correct and you have a GtkCellRendererText), you should be good to go.

(Thanks to gregier in irc.gimp.net/#gtk+ for some information.)